# What might be causing my ubuntu 14.04 vps SMTP port 25 to refuse connections, yet IMAP port 143 works?

Tags: php, email, smtp, ubuntu-14.04, mail-server

I just installed a webmail client called Rainloop on my ubuntu 14.04 vps and i it installed with no errors but when configuring my domains to work with SMTP i get `stream_socket_client(): unable to connect tcp://mail.example.com:25 (Connection refused)` yet IMAP connects to port `143` with no problems.Can someone please help me fix this error?

Comment: Well, you obviously need to take care that the smtp server is actually running and accepting connections from your client. That is nothing we can help with. Only you have access to your system and the configuration.

Comment: But a general remark: this is a place to ask _programming_ related questions. You'd better ask this question over at the `ServerFault` sister page.

Comment: Thanks for your help.actually your answer pointed me to the right direction.restarted my dovecot server and everything works now.

Comment: Just a newbie to these kind of forums so next time il be sure to ask my question in the right place. ;-)